# What is the super class for all the interfaces in java

Tags: java, class, interface

In java, 
    I know that super class of all "classes" is "Object" class.
    My doubt is,what is the super class for all the "interfaces" in java.

Comment: Consulting the Javadoc, or 'javap java.io.Serializable', would have told you the answer in ten seconds. -1 for zero prior research.

Answer (score 3):

Interfaces are not classes. Therefore, an interface cannot have a superclass, and your question is essentially invalid.

- [Is Interface a class?](http://www.coderanch.com/t/408974/java/java/Interface-class)
- [Is a Java interface an abstract class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/258285/is-a-java-interface-an-abstract-class)

Answer (score 1):

Interfaces can extend of each other but no a super class for interfaces.